# Azure Policy, exclude resource type

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am currently using this policy to successfully disable public access for Azure Storage accounts. However, when provisioning Function Apps or App Services, the same policy is preventing their creation. I am attempting to make adjustments to the policy to exclude Function Apps and App Services, allowing them to be created without being blocked by this Policy.

Here is the JSON I have tried, but it is not working as expected. It is still blocking the creation of Function Apps and App Services, indicating that Azure Storage account public access should be restricted.

Tried to use the this policy to exempt the function and app services but still being blocked by the Policy

```
type here  `{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "notequals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkAcls.defaultAction",
              "notEquals": "Deny"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Deny",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate policy definitions, one for Storage Accounts and another for Function Apps/App Services

For example, the function app policy:

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Audit"  // You can choose "Audit," "Deny," or "Disabled" as needed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is still failing as you suggested created two policy definitions 1) deny Storage public access 2) Allow app services/function app.